# This content can't be played on this Apple TV

Tags: appletv, error, itunes-store

Just watched ***Suits*** - S6; E13. I bought the season pass a while ago. Went to watch the next episode - *S6; E14,* but got the following error:

[image: This content can't be played on this Apple TV.]

> This content can't be played on this Apple TV.

Why / why not?

Skipped ahead to the episode after that one - *S6; E15,*  which is working fine.

What's going on?

Comment: My first thought would be it's a temporary problem at Apple's end. If it persists (say for 24hrs) then I'd contact Apple directly about it.

Comment: For how long is the failure persisting? Are date and time correct? I

Comment: Getting the same error message but it’s relating to videos that I’m trying to stream off of my computer. It only happens on videos that have been downloaded from iTunes. It does not happen to videos that were ripped from a DDVD. How could it be resolved for videos that are being streamed from a home computer?

Answer (score 3):

Just got off the phone with Apple support. Resolved by Settings>Apps>ITunes Movies and TV Shows>Quick Start and switched to off.